# How to design a flood with water elevation on a specific point?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, watershed, flood

Actually I have to know the flooding area caused by a rise of the water level due to the implementation of a dam.
So I would like to know if there is an extension or any tool in QGIS or GRASS which can allow me to have the representation of this flooding area according to the water level (a variable I need to change often)?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check GRASS r.lake function:

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.lake.html